# Remotely connect to SQL Server on a device which is connected to a public IP Address

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got `TP-link` router connected to `mikrotik`, and `mikrotik` is connected to the main network.

Where do I open port for a host (let's say **Host A**) which has a static IP address `X.X.X.37`, connected to the `TP-Link` router, so that when I do `telnet` to the public IP with the given port number, it will address to **Host A**.

If I'm able to do that, how do I access the SQL Server of **Host A** remotely. I've got a public IP Address of `X.X.118.1` (example). The TCP Port the device listens to is `43113`.

Comment: Seems you want expose SQL Ports over the internet (god help on securing your data). Rather, i would recommend to use VPN connections. You would get better answer, if you could mention the purpose and you scenario that lead to expose database over the internet

Comment: So, I was using a database on a computer in my network and accessing it from another pc, inside the network. Now I want to access the computer when I'm not under the same router. As I'm new to this, I'm not that sure how to do this in a proper way

Comment: When you say _"when I'm not under the same router"_, is that a branch location or home network, connections you wanted make from the network (branch/home) are just Database management/monitoring purpose or any application running from that location?